# Webpack html-webpack-plugin load favicons in template

Tags: webpack, html-webpack-plugin

I'm using Webpack with `html-webpack-plugin` and their provided template. 
I want to add a list of favicons in the header:

```
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="57x57" href="<%= htmlWebpackPlugin.extraFiles.apple-touch-icon-57x57 %>">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="60x60" href="<%= htmlWebpackPlugin.extraFiles.favicons.fav60%>">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="72x72" href="<%= htmlWebpackPlugin.extraFiles.favicons.fav72%>">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="76x76" href="favicons/apple-touch-icon-76x76.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="114x114" href="favicons/apple-touch-icon-114x114.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="120x120" href="favicons/apple-touch-icon-120x120.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="144x144" href="favicons/apple-touch-icon-144x144.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="152x152" href="favicons/apple-touch-icon-152x152.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180" href="favicons/apple-touch-icon-180x180.png">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="favicons/favicon-32x32.png" sizes="32x32">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="favicons/android-chrome-192x192.png" sizes="192x192">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="favicons/favicon-96x96.png" sizes="96x96">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="favicons/favicon-16x16.png" sizes="16x16">
<link rel="manifest" href="favicons/manifest.json">
<link rel="mask-icon" href="favicons/safari-pinned-tab.svg" color="#e53935">
<meta name="msapplication-TileColor" content="#da532c">
<meta name="msapplication-TileImage" content="favicon/mstile-144x144.png">
<meta name="theme-color" content="#e53935">
```

How can I include all the favicons in my webpack build, with or without `html-webpack-plugin`?

I tried adding them as extraFiles like the docs say, but they don't end up in my build folder.

*Note: The first 3 was me trying to something that didn't work.*

Comment: Still no answers? I have the same questions here.

Comment: Yup. I ended up hard coding it and copying the files manually.

Comment: I've used favicons-webpack-plugin and works like charm!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After numerous trials...still didn't manage to make it work with `html-webpack-plugin`, I did find a new library that helps with everything relating to titles, descriptions, keywords,...and almost any kind of header called `react-helmet`

You can find it here: https://github.com/nfl/react-helmet

Basically you add something like this in your main component

```
<Helmet
    link={[
        {"rel": "apple-touch-icon", "href": require('apple-touch-icon-57x57.png'), "sizes": "57x57"}
     ]}
 />
```

Hope this helps others.

Comment: Using something react-specific to a generic webpack problem does not seem like a real solution to me. :) Although in the end it does exactly the same way, what I am proposing it...

Comment: so, were you able to get away without html-webpack-plugin and only use react-helmet, or did you require both? if only react-helmet, can you share a basic example of setup?

Answer (score 22):

With Webpack v4.17.2, and html-webpack-plugin v3.2.0, I only had to do:

```
new HtmlWebPackPlugin({
  favicon: "./path/to/favicon",
  filename: "index.html",
  template: "./path/to/index.html",
}),
```

in the plugins section of the webpack config.

Comment: Confirmed with Webpack 4.43.0 and html-webpack-plugin 4.3.0

Answer (score 21):

You need to make sure, that the Images are processed by WebPack and thus that a matching loader exists for them (such as the [file-loader](https://github.com/webpack/file-loader)).

For that to work, you have to explicitly require the files in the corresponding attributes. To be able to explicitly require files in the index.html you have to use a loader in turn for index.html *itself*, that allows for processing JS inline.

This one really depends on your setup (i.e. whether you have setup html-webpack-*loader*); have a look at the [FAQ](https://github.com/ampedandwired/html-webpack-plugin/blob/master/docs/template-option.md), explaining the basics.

So assuming, you have somewhat along this:

//somewhere in your webpack config.js

```
plugins: [

  new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
    template: 'index.html',
    inject: 'head',
  }) //..
]
```

You can *require* *in* your index.html images like that:

```
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="120x120" href="${require('./favicons/apple-touch-icon-120x120.png')}">
```

This will try to load *apple-touch-icon-120x120.png* via WebPack, so you must make sure that there is a loader for it *and* the html-loader needs to be configured as well:

```
//somewhere in your webpack.config.js
module: {
  loaders: [
    {
      test: /\.png$/,
      loader: 'file?name=assets/icons/[name].[hash].[ext]'
    },

    {
      test: /\.html$/,
      loader: 'html',
      query: {
        interpolate: 'require'
      }
    } //..

   ] //..
}
```

You only have to use require for images that are *not* inside `<img>` - tags, those will get picked up automagically by html-webpack-loader.

Future versions of html-loader might change this behaviour -> https://github.com/webpack/html-loader/issues/17

Comment: Will try it out soon and update the answer if it works as this is more relevant (ie not react specific) to the question.

Comment: Not sure if due to a recent change, but using `href="<%= require('path/to/file.jpg') %>"` (`<%` instead of `${`) seemed to work fine w/out needing `html-loader`. Example here: https://github.com/jantimon/html-webpack-plugin/tree/master/examples/custom-template

Answer (score 11):

following up on this for anyone who comes across this in the future.

you'll need this in your template:

`<link href="{%=o.htmlWebpackPlugin.files.favicon%}" rel="shortcut icon">`

and its corresponding definition:

`new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
  favicon: "path/to/favicon"
}),`

in the `plugins` of your webpack config.

Comment: Nice! I think the syntax may have been updated. This worked for me - `<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="<%=htmlWebpackPlugin.files.favicon%>">`

Comment: this makes no sens since that very plugin is supposed to add many links

Comment: Looks like you don't need to add anything to your template now. It seems to inject the favicon for you

Answer (score 3):

For anyone who is looking for the solution,

You can use [copy-webpack-plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/copy-webpack-plugin), that will simply copy the files you specify to the output folder.

To copy all the assets from '../src/assets/favicons' to 'favicons' output folder do:

```js
      plugins: [
        new CopyWebpackPlugin([
          { from: `${__dirname}/../src/assets/favicons`, to: 'favicons' }
        ])
      ]
```

Note: ${__dirname} will resolve to the folder containing the webpack config file.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone still struggling with this issue, I've tested here basically everything said here, and found a quite simple and clean solution:

First, use the HtmlWebpackPlugin, simple and straight. Don't need to specify the *favicon* option in its configuration.

Second, declare your list of icons in the template `<head>`. Here is the "trick": when specifying the *href* for each icon, write as a *require*, like this: `href="${require('./favicon16.ico')}"`. This way, you can put as many favicon options as you want in your template.

**Explanation**: I'm not 100% sure about this, but it seems that HtmlWebpackPlugin now (tested at 3.2.0) handles interpolated `requires` in the HTML automatically, without requiring from developers to reconfigure the `html-loader` plugin.

Answer (score 1):

Best solution for me:
[favicons-webpak-plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/favicons-webpack-plugin)

webpack config:

```
const path = require('path');
const FaviconsWebpackPlugin = require('favicons-webpack-plugin');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

...
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      filename: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist/index.html'),
      template: 'index.html',
    }),
    new FaviconsWebpackPlugin({
      logo: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/img/icons/favicon-512.png'),
      prefix: '',
      publicPath: '../favicons',
      outputPath: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist/favicons'),
      inject: (htmlPlugin) => 
        path.basename(htmlPlugin.options.filename) === 'index.html',
    }),
  ],
```

Result:

- logl src => src/img/icons/favicon-512.png
- output files => dist/favicons/
- include to index.htm => dist/index.html
- it looks like => <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicons/favicon.ico"><link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="16x16" href="favicons/favicon-16x16.png">...

Comment: This is the best solution for me too, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you're using `HtmlWebpackPlugin`'s advanced config using `template` and `templateParameters` as a function, you might find it hard to achieve as we did, specifically if you're using `inject: false`.

[resource for advanced config setup](https://github.com/jantimon/html-webpack-plugin/tree/main/examples/template-parameters)

The point was to pass `favicon` to `HtmlWebpackPlugin` itself and then use it inside `templateParameters()` as an argument coming from `assets.favicon`:

```js
new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
  // 1. Your favicon goes here
  favicon: "path/to/favicon.ico",

  inject: false,
  template: "path/to/index.html",
  templateParameters: (compilation, assets, assetTags, options) => {
    // Compute stuff to be used as template parameters..
    const foo = "bar";

    return {
      compilation,
      webpackConfig: compilation.options,
      htmlWebpackPlugin: {
        tags: assetTags,
        files: assets,
        options,
      },

      // 2. Take 'favicon' from 'assets' so webpack
      // will be aware of its relative location
      favicon: assets.favicon,

      // This is why you used advanced settings...
      // You needed something custom
      foo,
    };
  },
})
```