# How do include multiple favicons in the webpack build w/ HTML Webpack Plugin?

Tags: webpack, html-webpack-plugin

I have tried including a wildcard, which broke the build; and multiple `favicon` field entries, which just used the last one entered. How do I support including multiple favicon files using this plugin?

Comment: Maybe this is helpful for you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35239733/webpack-html-webpack-plugin-load-favicons-in-template

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll need to also include the [favicons-webpack-plugin](https://github.com/jantimon/favicons-webpack-plugin#html-injection) to automatically generate all the favicons you need. the `html-webpack-plugin` doesn't automatically do that by default.

```sh
npm install --save-dev favicons-webpack-plugin
```

```js
plugins: [
  new FaviconsWebpackPlugin({
    // Your source logo (required)
    logo: './src/logo.png',
    // Enable caching and optionally specify the path to store cached data
    // Note: disabling caching may increase build times considerably
    cache: true,
    // Override the publicPath option usually read from webpack configuration
    publicPath: '/static',
    // The directory to output the assets relative to the webpack output dir.
    // Relative string paths are allowed here ie '../public/static'. If this
    // option is not set, `prefix` is used.
    outputPath: '/public/static',
    // Prefix path for generated assets
    prefix: 'assets/',
    // Inject html links/metadata (requires html-webpack-plugin).
    // This option accepts arguments of different types:
    //  * boolean
    //    `false`: disables injection
    //    `true`: enables injection if that is not disabled in html-webpack-plugin
    //  * function
    //    any predicate that takes an instance of html-webpack-plugin and returns either
    //    `true` or `false` to control the injection of html metadata for the html files
    //    generated by this instance.
    inject: true,

    // Favicons configuration options (see below)
    favicons: {
      ...
    }
  })
]
```

And then include just the explicit favicon configuration you want, which is available from the `favicon` [npm package](https://github.com/itgalaxy/favicons#usage):

```js
favicons {
        path: "/",                                // Path for overriding default icons path. `string`
        appName: null,                            // Your application's name. `string`
        appShortName: null,                       // Your application's short_name. `string`. Optional. If not set, appName will be used
        appDescription: null,                     // Your application's description. `string`
        developerName: null,                      // Your (or your developer's) name. `string`
        developerURL: null,                       // Your (or your developer's) URL. `string`
        dir: "auto",                              // Primary text direction for name, short_name, and description
        lang: "en-US",                            // Primary language for name and short_name
        background: "#fff",                       // Background colour for flattened icons. `string`
        theme_color: "#fff",                      // Theme color user for example in Android's task switcher. `string`
        appleStatusBarStyle: "black-translucent", // Style for Apple status bar: "black-translucent", "default", "black". `string`
        display: "standalone",                    // Preferred display mode: "fullscreen", "standalone", "minimal-ui" or "browser". `string`
        orientation: "any",                       // Default orientation: "any", "natural", "portrait" or "landscape". `string`
        scope: "/",                               // set of URLs that the browser considers within your app
        start_url: "/?homescreen=1",              // Start URL when launching the application from a device. `string`
        version: "1.0",                           // Your application's version string. `string`
        logging: false,                           // Print logs to console? `boolean`
        pixel_art: false,                         // Keeps pixels "sharp" when scaling up, for pixel art.  Only supported in offline mode.
        loadManifestWithCredentials: false,       // Browsers don't send cookies when fetching a manifest, enable this to fix that. `boolean`
        icons: {
            // Platform Options:
            // - offset - offset in percentage
            // - background:
            //   * false - use default
            //   * true - force use default, e.g. set background for Android icons
            //   * color - set background for the specified icons
            //   * mask - apply mask in order to create circle icon (applied by default for firefox). `boolean`
            //   * overlayGlow - apply glow effect after mask has been applied (applied by default for firefox). `boolean`
            //   * overlayShadow - apply drop shadow after mask has been applied .`boolean`
            //
            android: true,              // Create Android homescreen icon. `boolean` or `{ offset, background, mask, overlayGlow, overlayShadow }` or an array of sources
            appleIcon: true,            // Create Apple touch icons. `boolean` or `{ offset, background, mask, overlayGlow, overlayShadow }` or an array of sources
            appleStartup: true,         // Create Apple startup images. `boolean` or `{ offset, background, mask, overlayGlow, overlayShadow }` or an array of sources
            coast: true,                // Create Opera Coast icon. `boolean` or `{ offset, background, mask, overlayGlow, overlayShadow }` or an array of sources
            favicons: true,             // Create regular favicons. `boolean` or `{ offset, background, mask, overlayGlow, overlayShadow }` or an array of sources
            firefox: true,              // Create Firefox OS icons. `boolean` or `{ offset, background, mask, overlayGlow, overlayShadow }` or an array of sources
            windows: true,              // Create Windows 8 tile icons. `boolean` or `{ offset, background, mask, overlayGlow, overlayShadow }` or an array of sources
            yandex: true                // Create Yandex browser icon. `boolean` or `{ offset, background, mask, overlayGlow, overlayShadow }` or an array of sources
        }
    }
```